# get custom post archieve by month

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to make a custom post archieve template where I will display only the custom post by month..

I added this in `archieve.php`

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news_letter', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    /** Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
     * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
     */
     get_template_part( 'newletter', get_post_format() );
```

where `news_letter` is my custom post...by this I am getting all post without any sorting of month, means I am getting all month post in December link.

to make archieve link I used this:

```
<li><?php wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'monthly','order'=>'ASC')); ?></li>
```

any help would be appreciate..

Thanks for your time and sharing knowledge... :)

Comment: `wp_get_archives` is used for native `posts` there is no option to get archive lists of custom post type from wordpress (as far as i know).

Comment: By the way you can read this [article](http://www.codefap.com/2013/04/create-monthly-archives-page-in-wordpress/). It will show you how to make archive lists of custom post types.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not used **'has_archive'** parameter when creating custom post type.

Please refer below code for creating custom post type.

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

    function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'news_letter',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'News Letter' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'News Letter' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
      }
```

then in **archive-{posttype}.php** file paste below code:

```
<?php
get_header();
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Thanks.

Comment: It is same...no difference... :(

Comment: Difference is, page name you need to create for displaying archive posts, that should be **archive-{posttype}.php** not only archive.php

Comment: i have `archive-news_letter.php`